# Using SQLite with Xamarin.Forms cross-platform project

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have used Visual Studio 2017 Community edition to create a plain vanilla cross platform PCL project, and would like to use SQLite. The only thing done to the project(s) was the use of Nuget to update all packages that needed updating.

Then, following the instructions on the Xamarin website at

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/

I used Nuget to install sqlite-net-pcl,
[image: sqlite-net-pcl info]

It all seemed to work OK, except at the end the following error appears.

[image: Image showing error at end of the Nuget installation process]

I presume the documentation is slightly dated. Should I change the target .NET framework. If so, to what?

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.3 SQLite-Net-PCL is actually no longer a PCL, it is a .Net standard library.

You need to install version 1.2.0 of the NuGet package to use it inside a PCL - from the nuget package manager you can select a version so install v1.2.0 into all your projects.

Answer (score 0):

The library above worked OK as a PCL library, but what I disliked was that the platforms were split out in to separate DLLs so you had a different dependency for each platform.

This library is for .NET Standard and only has a single DLL for all platforms:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/SQLite.Net.Standard

It does not support the ORM like functionality in the above library though.